# Alternating sum of binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm currently playing with some sequence and series studying asymptotic properties and stuff and I'd need to know if it exists a closed form for:

$$s^k_n:=\sum_{l=0}^n(-1)^l{{l+k}\choose k}$$

for $k\in \mathbb{N}$. so far I know:

$$s^0_n=\left[ \frac n2 \right]$$

$$s^1_n=\frac {1+(2n+3)(-1)^n}4$$

any help (ways to do it by induction, recursive formula, asymptotic behavior, source, etc) is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$s^k_n=2^{-k-1}+(-1)^n\left(^{n+k+1}_{\ \ \ \ k}\right)hypergeom([1,n+k+2],[n+2],-1)$$

$$s^k_\infty=2^{-k-1}$$

Comment: My guess is that it is asymptotic to $n^{k+1}$, is this correct?

Comment: For the "sum" of the series you used Cesaro's summation right? Because that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: It's easy to prove the Cesaro sum of the alternating series is $2^{-k-1}$ I was just wondering if you used some other methods.